# How do I create a class (OOP) that compares two words to be the same, even if they're anagrams

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

Trying to create an OOP using class to compare two words and return True if they're the same and false if not. Words can be anagrams/upper/lower case versions of each other and still be true (W1 = sTop, W2 = Pots, W1 == W2 result: True) I am new to coding, so I am struggling in the attribute part of this code. How do I get it to read the word as the same under these conditions.

I have gone through this site as well as others to find the structure and overall idea behind OOP and have pieced together what I think to be correct, however, I know it's not complete and will kick errors when I run it. I've tried calling the methods under str using my classes grade scope and it failed which I expected. Any help in explaining/writing this problem would be great. Please excuse my novice ability in coding.

class Word:

```
def _init_(self, word):
    self.word = word


def _str_(self):
    w1 == w2
    return self.lower(word)


Expected outcomes:

Examples
word1 = Word("post")
word2 = Word("stop")
word1 == word2

Result: True
word1 = Word("")
word2 = Word("")
word1 == word2

Result: True
word1 = Word("aBlE")
str(word1)

Result: able
word1 = Word("able")
word2 = Word("baker")
word1 == word2

Result: False
word1 = Word("Hi there! :-)")
word2 = Word("Hit here! :-)")
word1 == word2

Result: True
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all,
  The dunder (double-underscore: '__') methods are special methods used for you or python to hook into your code, for example implementing `__len__` on a class will allow you to run `len(MyClass)` instead of `MyClass.__len__()`. so in essence, your defining `__str__` isn't your desired step.
- Second, in you `__str__` method you are trying to compare `w1 == w2` which are 2 variables which you haven't defined or accepted as arguments to your function.

My answer is, not always do you need to use OOP, for example your case can be defined as a simple function as follows

### edit

As I see I accidentally mixed up **anagram** with **palindrome**, I am adding the anagram version as well.

```
def is_anagram(w1, w2):
    return sorted(w1.lower()) == sorted(w2.lower())

# and I am keeping just for reference sake the palindrome one.
def is_palindrome(w1, w2):
    return w1.lower() == w2.lower()[::-1]
```

What I am doing in the *anagram function* is first I am lowercasing the words so I  can compare the characters regardless of case, and then I am using the `sorted` function which takes a sequence (which `str` is a sequence) and sorts it), and then we compare the 2 to see if they are indeed anagrams of each other.

What I am doing in the *palindrome function* is accepting to strings and then comparing the lowercased version of `w1` to the reveresed lowercase version of `w2`, I am reversing the string by using a slice which starts at the default index (implicit as it is blank before the first colon), default stop, and a step of negative 1, which in effect reverses the string.

In any case, I wish you great luck on your programming journey!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got it now.

Comment: You are 100% correct! And I see you answered the question very nicely as well!

Answer (score 1):

Anagrams are words containing exactly the same letters, in the same numbers. You can write a function that takes in two words, sorts the letters, and compare them one by one.

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    return sorted(word1.lower()) == sorted(word2.lower())

are_anagrams('abBa', 'BAba'), are_anagrams('abby', 'baba')
```

If you wanted to use a class, you could override the `__eq__` dunder method that governs the behavior of operator `==`:

Maybe something like this:

```
class AnagramWords:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.cmp = sorted(self.word.lower())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """returns True if self is an anagram of other
        """
        if isinstance(other, str):
            other = AnagramWords(other)
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self.cmp == other.cmp
        raise NotImplementedError(f'AnagramWord cannot compare to {type(other)}')


def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    return sorted(list(word1.lower())) == sorted(list(word2.lower()))

are_anagrams('abBa', 'BAba'), are_anagrams('abby', 'baba')  # True, False

w1 = AnagramWords('AbBA')
w2 = AnagramWords('BBaa')
w3 = AnagramWords('bABy')
print(w1 == w2, w2 == w3)   # True, False

print(w3 == 123)   # NotImplementedError: AnagramWord cannot compare to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: You can apply `sorted` to a string directly without having to cast it to a list first, i.e. `sorted(word1.lower()) == sorted(word2.lower())`.